# It is possible to save image like by rightclick in browser?

Tags: python, image, selenium

It is possible to save image on site when selenium is minimized?
At the moment i using code:

```
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="image_img"]')
img.screenshot('C:/foo.png')
```

This ofcourse works, but this option opens the browser just as it takes a screenshot.
Is it possible to save an image from a given xpath in a minimized browser?

Unfortunately, downloading the url of the photo is pointless, because this image is generated only once and when I download the photo via the url, I will get an empty file or the image is other what should be.

site: https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need selenium to get pictures from the website, you can use this code

to download image directly to your local.

```
import requests

r1 = requests.get("https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image")
r1.raise_for_status()

print(r1.status_code, r1.reason)

tts_url = 'https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image'

r2 = requests.get(tts_url, timeout=100, cookies=r1.cookies)
print(r2.status_code, r2.reason)

try:
    with open('test.jpeg', "w+b") as f:
        f.write(r2.content)
except IOError:
    print("IOError: could not write a file")
```